# If $\int_a ^b f df=0$ and f is continuous, then f is the function constant $0$

Tags: integration, analysis

I have been studied some properties of Riemann Stieltjes integral, and i found this: If  $\int_a ^b f df=0$ and f is continuous for every $a<b$ in $R$, then f is the function constant $0$ without proof

I know, by definition $\int_a ^b f df = \sum_{i=0} ^{n} f(\lambda_i)(f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1}))$ 
and if $f$ is constant, is clear  $(f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1}))=0$ for every $i$
but why $f$ must be a constant zero?

Comment: Isn't $\int_a ^b f df=0$ for every constant function $f$, not only for the zero function?

Comment: That is  my question

Comment: @MartinR No. $\int^b_a k dx$ = k(b-a). It's the area of the rectangle with height k. To answer the OP, think of the function y = -2x+1.whose graph is the line that connects (0,1) to (1,-1). The integral of this function is 0 but the function is non-constant.

Comment: @JoelPereira: The question is about the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int f \, df$, not about  the (Riemann) integral $\int f \, dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing about $f$ being monotone or of bounded variation is specified here.  These are the typical assumptions for Riemann-Stieltjes integrators.  That limits the available tools for proving this.

Nevertheless, stating that $\int_a^b f \, df = 0$ for all $a < b$ implies that $f$ can be assumed to be RS integrable with respect to $f$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P: a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$ such that for any choice of intermediate points $\xi_j \in [x_{j-1},x_j]$,

$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n f(\xi_j)(f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})) \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Thus,

$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n (f(x_j)+f(x_{j-1}))(f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})) \right|\leqslant \left|\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_{j-1})(f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1}) \right|+\left|\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j)(f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})) \right| < \epsilon,$$

and,

$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n (f(x_j)+f(x_{j-1}))(f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})) \right| = \left|\sum_{j=1}^n ((f(x_j))^2 - (f(x_{j-1}))^2)\right| = \left|(f(b))^2 - (f(a))^2\right| < \epsilon$$

This implies that $(f(b))^2 = (f(a))^2$ and $f(b) = \pm f(a)$.

Since, $f$ is continuous, taking $a$ close to $b$ rules out $f(b) = -f(a)$.

The argument can be extended, proving that $f(a)$ is constant for all $a \in \mathbb{R}.$

**Addendum**

Also, the question of whether or not $0$ is the only admissible constant is worth considering.  Assume that for some fixed point $a$, we have $f(a) > 0$. Then for any other distant point $b$ we immediately know that $f(b) = \pm f(a)$. If $f(b) < 0$ then by continuity and the intermediate value property there would have to exist a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$ where $f(c) = 0$. But $f(c) = \pm f(a)$ and this would give us the contradiction that $f(a) = 0$. Thus, $f(x) = f(a)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The function could take any constant value $c$.  $\int_a^bf \,df = 0$ for $f(x) = c$.

Comment: That is essentially the proof of “integration by parts” for this special case: $\int_a^b f \, df = f^2(b) - f^2(a) - \int_a^b f \, df$, so that $\int_a^b f \, df=0$  implies $f^2(b) = f^2(a) $.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes -- excellent point.  Only knowing that $f$ is RS integrable with respect to $g$ it follows that $g$ is integrable with respect to $f$ and $\int_a^b f \, dg = f(b)g(b) - f(a) g(a) - \int_a^b g \, df$.

Answer (score 1):

(This is essentially [RRL's argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3241091/42969), only simplified using “integration by parts,” which is a [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties) of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals.)

If $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to itself on $[a, b]$ then integration by parts gives
$$
 \int_a^b f \, df = f^2(b) - f^2(a) - \int_a^b f \, df \\
\implies f^2(b) - f^2(a) = \frac 12 \int_a^b f \, df \, .
$$

It follows that $\int_a^b f \, df = 0$ for all $a < b$ if and only if $f^2$ is constant on $\Bbb R$. If $f$ is continuous then this is equivalent to $f$ being constant on $\Bbb R$.

As you already observed, the constant value is not necessarily zero.